# Opencart 2.0.3.1 Header Problems

Tags: opencart2.x

So, I have modified the `header.tpl` file in **OpenCart 2.0.3.1** by removing the wishlist, linking the `telephone#` as a click to call and added a custom class called `"great-barbecue"`. It worked in one version that I earlier installed. When that whole thing went sideways, I started from scratch and now the wishlist still shows up, the phone# and icon are not "click to call" and my custom class is not appearing at all? Here is a link to the code I have for `header.tpl` in `catalog/view/theme/default/template/common` [header template](http://chestersbbq.com/Groton/catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/header.tpl)

My site [chestersbbq.com/Groton](http://chestersbbq.com/Groton/index.php?route=common/home)

When I copy and paste the code I get an error telling me to indent all code with 4 spaces and I really don't have time for that, hence the link. I have tried it in all browsers and when I look at the source code for the page the wishlist is still there, the phone still links to contact and my custom html is not there. I don't know how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

nice site, I have found this in the open cart forums, it looks like you have to remove all instances of the wish list. Try this and let me know how it goes.

http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=32955

Comment: Thank you. I will try this after I am done entering products. I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Yeah, that is the post I used to edit the header.tpl file. I did all of that but for some reason, the wishlist still comes up and I have all the above mentioned problems. If you look at the file that is on my server that I have linked to the post you will note that wishlist is removed, I have linked the phone for click to call and my custom class "great-barbecue" is there but they are not showing up in any browser with ALL cache removed on the server and in the browsers. Thank you anyway. I will figure it out somehow.

Comment: When, You will any changes in file. So, You have to clear and refresh the modification cache to update the system. You can clear and refresh by top right buttons on **Extension > Modification** page in admin panel. then check it.

Comment: Worked like a charm. All I had to do was refresh the modifications page. Thank you so much:-)

Comment: So...I have the site finished but the tel: link is only working on the icon and not the number itself. This is the code I have now and I have tried everything I can think of to get the number itself linked but nothing is working <li><a href="tel:8604496868"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></a> <a href="tel:8604496868">(860)449-6868</a></li>
Any ideas?
Thanks:)

Comment: Hi @210USA can you provide a link to the site again, the old one no longer works